# Fastapi showing empty list when fetching data from mongodb database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, fastapi

I am trying to fetch data using fastapi.

my database.py to enter data into EventDetails collection

```
import pymongo
import scrap4
from backend.model import EventDetails

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/')

mydb = client['Events']  #database
events = mydb.EventDetails #collection EventDetails

events.insert_many(scrap4.events_list) #data insert
```

model.py

```
from mongoengine import Document,StringField,DateTimeField,URLField

class EventDetails(Document):
    url   = URLField()
    title = StringField()
    date  = DateTimeField()
    link  = URLField()
```

get_api.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from backend.model import EventDetails
from mongoengine import connect

app = FastAPI()
connect(db="Events",host = "127.0.0.1",port = 27017)

@app.get("/get_all_events")
def get_all_events():
    details = EventDetails.objects().to_json()
    return {"Event_Details" : details}
```

In the output there is a empty list, although the EventDetails database has entries.

```
{"Event_Details":"[]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongo collections are case sensitive and by default MongoEngine will snake_case your Document class name (see [doc](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#document-collections))

> The name of the collection is by default the name of the class converted to snake_case (e.g if your Document class is named CompanyUser, the corresponding collection would be company_user). I

In your case you are inserting with pymongo in a collection named "EventDetails" but your MongoEngine model is mapped to a collection named "event_details". So you are basically not inserting and reading from the same collection.

See below:

```
from mongoengine import *
connect(db="Events",host = "127.0.0.1",port = 27017)

class EventDetails(Document):
    url   = URLField()
    title = StringField()
    date  = DateTimeField()
    link  = URLField()

coll = EventDetails._get_collection()
print(coll.name)    # prints "event_details"
```

you have 2 options here:

- fix your pymongo insert so it points to collection "event_details"
- force the name of your MongoEngine Document's collection (through meta = {'collection': 'EventDetails'})